# Why is my CSS relative positioning not working?

Tags: css, css-position

I am having trouble moving any of my divs with relative/ absolute ect positioning. Any help would be appreciated, cheers.

Code:

```
<div id="game"><img src="gta-game.jpg" height="100" width="70" alt="gta"/></div></li>
    <div id="gamename">Grand Theft Auto V</div>
    <div id="rating">9/10<div>
    <div id="system">PS4</div>
```

CSS:

```
#game{
height: 100px;
width: 70px;
display: relative;
left: 50px;
}
#gamename{
display: relative;
right: 50px;
}
#rating{
display: relative;
right: 100px;
}
#system{
display: relative;
right: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `display`. You should be using `position`. Try this:

```
#game{
height: 100px;
width: 70px;
position: relative;
left: 50px;
}
#gamename{
position: relative;
right: 50px;
}
#rating{
position: relative;
right: 100px;
}
#system{
position: relative;
right: 200px;
}
```

Comment: @MattLoughton Hey dude, you're welcome, but if I can ask, what's with the GTA and rating? Is it on a game rating site or something?

Comment: yeah, im creating a site based on playstation for an assignment.

Answer (score 2):

The correct property is `position: relative`, not `display: relative`.